# Error when Method and Namespace is same name

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I have 2 projects, both using AutoMapper with the same version. So both of the project need to configure the profile by using this code

```cs
 public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfile()
        {
            //CreateMap goes here
        }       
    }
```

As you see, I will inherit class `Profile` from AutoMapper. But the problem happen on another project.

Namespace for this project is `Profile.API`. So what happen is I got the error `'Profile' is a namespace but is used like a type`

Here is my full code for class `AutoMapperProfile`

```cs
using AutoMapper;


namespace Profile.API.Infrastructure.AutoMapper
{
    public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfile()
        {
            //CreateMap goes here
        }       
    }
}
```

Need a advice

Comment: Fully Qualify the base class: `AutoMapperProfile : Fully.Qualified.Profile`.

Comment: Cannot, still error @ErikPhilips

Comment: Problem solved, just rename folder from 'AutoMapper' to another name. Then can use like `AutoMapperProfile : AutoMapper.Profile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the Automapper `using` an alias:

```
using AM = AutoMapper;

namespace Profile.API.Infrastructure.AutoMapper
{
    public class AutoMapperProfile : AM.Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfile()
        {
            //CreateMap goes here
        }
    }
}
```